# Quartz jobs.xml absoulute path

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jobs

I am trying hard to debug the exact issue while using absolute path in quartz.properties. 
Jar: Quartz-all-2.1.1.jar
Server: weblogic

quartz.properties:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = QuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 8
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 8
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames =e:\\jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 10
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false
```

I also tried using

```
1) file://e:/jobs.xml
2) e:/jobs.xml
3) e:\jobs.xml
```

Nothing worked and always get below exception

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: e
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:574)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:252)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:222)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder.parse(JXDocumentBuilder.java:155)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilder.parse(RegistryDocumentBuilder.java:163)
    at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.process(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:550)
    at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.processFile(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:514)
    at org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.processFileAndScheduleJobs(XMLSchedulingDataProcessor.java:896)
    at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.processFile(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:329)
    at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.start(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:256)
    at org.quartz.plugins.SchedulerPluginWithUserTransactionSupport.start(SchedulerPluginWithUserTransactionSupport.java:144)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.startPlugins(QuartzScheduler.java:2342)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:527)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:143)
```

Regards
Priya

Comment: well, could you enable the logging of `org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor` (slf4j) and show us what is outputted by this line: `log.info("Parsing XML from stream with systemId: " + systemId);` of class `XMLSchedulingDataProcessor`

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with `file:/e:/jobs.xml`.

At least, this is a valid URL.

HIH

Comment: Thanks, But it didn't work either. It gives error:org.quartz.SchedulerException: File named 'file:/e:/jobs.xml' does not exist.
 at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin$JobFile.initialize(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:411)
 at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin$JobFile.<init>(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:361)
 at org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.initialize(XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.java:208)
 at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1278)

Comment: according to the source of methodorg.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.JobFile#initialize you don't need to use an URL if the file is located on your file system. Does it work with `org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = e:/jobs.xml`. If not, what it the exception ?

Comment: I get exception like java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: e
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:574)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)